# Windows Form not recognized C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a new form to look back at printed labels. Simple form to keep track of the Job# printed. However when I try and code the button click to showdialog for the form, nothing happens. It does not recognize that I created the form at all.

I added this EditProductsForm above the JobRecord just to see if there was something wrong with the Button Click. This works fine. On my screen the EditProductsForm is light blue and is shown in the prediction.

```
        EditProductsForm editProductsForm = new EditProductsForm();
        editProductsForm.Show();
```

The JobRecord is not show in prediction and has the red line underneath showing an error?!

```
        JobRecord jobRecord = new JobRecord();
        jobrecord.Showdialog();
```

Any help as to what might have been changed?

Comment: different namespace?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. It doesn't help anyone that you explain the code if you don't post it

Comment: Move your mouse onto that red line and read what it says (prediction = intellisense ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't imported the proper namespaces where those class file resides like

```
using <namespace_name_where_form_class_defined>;
```

Comment: Or it could be a private class, or a nested one, or in another not-referenced assembly...

Comment: Sorry thought I had when I posted the comment.